# How to recognize double clicks when closing WPF context menu

Tags: wpf, events, click, contextmenu, double-click

This is an example that highlights the problem:

```
<TextBlock Text="double click me" Width="150" Height="25"
           ContextMenuOpening="TextBlock_ContextMenuOpening"
           Mouse.MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="test" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

When the context menu is open, I double click the TextBlock. The first hit of `TextBlock_MouseDown` has `e.ClickCount = 1` as expected, but so does the second. Is there any way I can get the clicks to be part of the same chain?

Answer (score 0):

The first click closes the `ContextMenu` so you should be able to handle the `ContextMenuClosing` and then compare the total time elapsed between when the `ContextMenu` was closed and when the `TextBlock` was clicked again, e.g.:

```
DateTime dt;
private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds <= 0.3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("double click detected!");
        dt = DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}

private void TextBlock_ContextMenuClosing(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    dt = DateTime.Now;
}
```

---

```
<TextBlock Text="double click me" Width="150" Height="25"
           ContextMenuClosing="TextBlock_ContextMenuClosing"
           Mouse.MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="test" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using *StaysOpenOnClick="True"*. You can close it after the double click:

```
    <TextBlock Text="double click me" Width="150" Height="25" >
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="cm">
                <MenuItem PreviewMouseDoubleClick="MenuItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Header="test" 
                      StaysOpenOnClick="True" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
```

in code:

```
    private void MenuItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        cm.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Also note that there is a *StaysOpen* property in ContextMenu too, and you can use it.